# Trouble instantiating gdx-pay purchaseManager in my game

Tags: android, libgdx, gdx-pay

I am trying to set up gdx-pay in my game.  I have followed the official readme (https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/), but can't seem to instantiate the PurchaseManager in my AndroidLauncher.

I have set up a class that handles PurchaseManager installation, but every time I try to instantiate it in the AndroidLauncher I get this error:

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{appPackage.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Support for pending purchases must be enabled. Enable this by calling 'enablePendingPurchases()' on BillingClientBuilder."

The readme says to add this to the AndroidLauncher onCreate
`game.purchaseManager = new PurchaseManagerGoogleBilling(this);`
The problem is that I have to add this
`ProjectName.purchaseManager = new PurchaseManagerGoogleBilling(this);`
This give me an error saying that I have to make purchaseManager static in my ProjectName class
When I do this, I get the RuntimeException mentioned above.
The sample gdx-pay project instantiates PurchaseManager with this code

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends GenericAndroidLauncher {
    @Override
    protected void initFlavor(GdxPayApp game) {
        super.initFlavor(game);
        game.purchaseManager = new PurchaseManagerGoogleBilling(this);
    }
}
```

When I try this, @Override is invalid and initFlavor does not exist.  I tried looking for initFlavor in the gdx-pay files, but had no luck finding anything...
Thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that the following line in my android gradle was the issue

`implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.1'`

Gdx-pay takes care of this automatically and uses client 1.1
Setting the billingclient to 2.0.1 was the problem.  I was able to fix it by deleting that line.  Big thanks to the libGdx discord guys!